# TypeError: decode() argument 'encoding' must be str, not None

Tags: python

I've been trying to make a script to check if a random website exists and then opens it if it does exist, but I keep getting a bunch of different errors. Here is my code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from html.parser import HTMLParser
import os
from http.client import HTTPConnection
from urllib.parse import urljoin, urlunparse
from urllib.request import urlretrieve
from html.parser import HTMLParser    
class ImageParser(HTMLParser):
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag != 'img':
            return
        if not hasattr(self, 'result'):
            self.result = []
        for name, value in attrs:
            if name == 'src':
                self.result.append(value)
def download_image(url, data):
    if not os.path.exists('DOWNLOAD'):
        os.makedirs('DOWNLOAD')
    parser = ImageParser()
    parser.feed(data)
    dataSet = set(x for x in parser.result)
    for x in sorted(dataSet) :
        imageUrl = urljoin(url, x)
        basename = os.path.basename(imageUrl)
        targetFile = os.path.join('DOWNLOAD', basename)
        print("Downloading...", imageUrl)
        urlretrieve(imageUrl, targetFile)

def main():
    host = "www.jejunu.ac.kr"
    conn = HTTPConnection(host)
    conn.request("GET", '/main')
    resp = conn.getresponse()
    charset = resp.msg.get_param('charset')
    data = resp.read().decode(charset)
    conn.close()
    print("\n>>>>>>>>> Download Images from", host)
    url = urlunparse(('http', host, '', '', '', ''))
    download_image(url, data)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And here is the error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\웹프로그래밍 (1)\test.py", line 43, in <module>
        main()
      File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\웹프로그래밍 (1)\test.py", line 37, in main
        data = resp.read().decode(charset)
    TypeError: decode() argument 'encoding' must be str, not None
```

Comment: That's not the same error as in your question title.

Answer (score 0):

Probably no charset is provided, most likely it will be utf8, change main to the following:

```
def main():
    host = "www.jejunu.ac.kr"
    conn = HTTPConnection(host)
    conn.request("GET", '/main')
    resp = conn.getresponse()
    charset = resp.msg.get_param('charset')
    if charset is None:
      charset = 'utf8'
    data = resp.read().decode(charset)
    conn.close()
    print("\n>>>>>>>>> Download Images from", host)
    url = urlunparse(('http', host, '', '', '', ''))
    download_image(url, data)
```

Or you might try a little bit different approach:

```
from urllib import request
reqURL = request.urlopen("www.jejunu.ac.kr")
encoding = reqURL.headers.get_content_charset()
data = reqURL.read().decode(charset)
```